# Do I need to service rear Drum Brakes?

Tags: brakes, mitsubishi

Car: 2006 Mitsubishi Lancer ES 2.0L SOHC Automatic

I recently rotated my wheels and noticed that the rear wheels make a slight grinding noise. After some research on the internet, I think the issue could be due to rust in the brake drum. **There is no problem with braking and I don't hear any noise when I am driving.** I hear it only when I jack the car up and move the wheel by hand.

Do I need to get my drum brakes serviced? Or can I just keep driving like this?

I don't want to do it my self and don't want to take it to a mechanic unless it is really necessary.

Note: The noticed the noise before removing the wheels, **and** after as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think there could be an issue with the brakes, you need to have them inspected. You should pull the drum off of the brakes and see what's going on. Check the depth of the friction material on the shoe to ensure there is enough "meat" on them to do the work for you. If you are unfamiliar with how to do it or what to look for, take the car to a trusted mechanic (one which won't say you need them whether you do or not).

You need to remember with vehicle braking, about 60% of the braking is done at the front of the vehicle. Just because you feel that the brakes are working well, doesn't mean there isn't an issue with the rear brakes. If you were to get into a situation where you need to perform some extreme braking (emergency braking) and the rear brakes aren't doing there job, your stopping distance will be increased. While they only do about 40% of the braking, they are there for a purpose and should be respected as such. For your safety, your passengers, and those you drive around, get them inspected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I took it to a mechanic and there was some rust inside the drum. He removed the rust with a sander and now I don't hear any noise.